# How to generate one time password to add User via Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph to add a new user to Azure AD and figured I would use Membership.GeneratePassword to get the one-time password. What I am unsure of whether the result will pass the requirements for such a password.  I noticed that when adding a user via the portal the password generated doesn't actually meet requirements for a strong password in AAD, which probably bodes well for use of GeneratePassword.

Even better would be to leverage whatever Azure Portal is using - does anyone know what that algorithm is or the requirement for the one-time password?